# Suggestions on extracting text from uploaded documents

Tags: sql, apache-poi, text-extraction

I currently have a number of documents uploaded to my website on a daily basis (.doc, .docx, .odt, pdf) and these docs are stored in a sql database (mediumblob).

Currently I open the docs from the database and cut and paste a text version into a field in the database for a quick reference and search function.

I'm looking to automate this "cut & paste" process - formatting isn't a real concern just as long as I can extract the text - and was hoping that some people may be able to suggest a good route to go down?

I've tried manipulating the content of the blob field using regex but it is not really working.

I've been looking at Apache POI with a view to extracting the text at the point of upload but I can't help thinking that this maybe a bit of an overkill given my relatively simple needs.

Given the various document formats I encounter and the current storing of the content in a blob field would Apache POI be the best solution to use in this instance or can anybody suggest an alternative?

Help and suggestions greatly appreciated.

Chris

Comment: I think POI is the standard solution; so if you get stuck, it will be the one that you're most likely to be able to find help with.  I can't think of any reason for you not to use it.

Comment: Thanks for the David - I'll try Tika in this instance given the extra formats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) will only work for the Microsoft Office formats (.xls, .docx, .msg etc). For these formats, it provides classes for working with the files (always read, for many write support too), as well as text extractors.

For a general text extraction framework, you should look at [Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/). Tika uses POI internally to handle the Microsoft formats, and uses a number of other libraries to handle different formats. Tika will, for example, handle both PDF and ODF/ODT, which are the other two file formats you mentioned in the question.

There are some quick start tutorials and examples on the [Apache Tika website](http://tika.apache.org/), I'd suggest you have a look through. It's very quick to get started with, and you should be able to easily change your code to send the document through Tika during upload to get a plain text version, or event XHTML if that's more helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks Gagravarr - I'll try and see if I can get Tika to work for me.